# How to use the url_launcher package to just open the default mail app, without having to to compose

Tags: android, flutter, dart, email, url-launcher

```
await launchUrl(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
```

Takes me to compose, I just want to open the mail app.

I expected to open the mail app, but it's not working, please suggest any package or lib for it

Answer (score 2):

You can use like below :

```
launch("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox")
```

Or you can  use this package:

https://pub.dev/packages/external_app_launcher

Answer (score 1):

this will help you to open app **device_apps 2.2.0**

link : https://pub.dev/packages/device_apps

call this code using package name

```
DeviceApps.openApp('com.google.android.gm');
```